# É possível modificar um valor de um vetor com assign() no R?

Tags: r

Suponhamos que temos

```
x <- "teste"
```

Dá para atribuir uma outra string a teste, utilizando assign:

```
assign(x, 1:5)
```

Assim:

> teste
>
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5

Seria possível eu modificar algum dos valores do vetor usando assign?
Algo como:

```
assign("teste[1]", 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não dá para fazer diretamente com o `assign`. Conforme consta na ajuda:

> assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to
>   set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc.

Se você quiser utilizar o `assign`, uma solução seria fazer uma cópia temporária antes:

```
temp <- get("teste")
temp[1] <- 2
assign("teste", temp)
teste
[1] 2 2 3 4 5
```

Você poderia criar uma função que faça isso:

```
assign2 <- function(x, i, value){
  temp <- get(x, envir = parent.frame())
  temp[i] <- value
  assign(x, temp, envir = parent.frame())
}

x <- "teste"

assign(x, 1:5)
teste
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

assign2(x, 1, 2)
teste
[1] 2 2 3 4 5
```

Uma outra forma não recomendada de fazer algo semelhante seria com `eval` e `parse`:

```
eval(parse(text = paste("teste[1]", "<-", 2)))
```

Em todos esses casos, é provável que tenha uma solução mais simples a depender do problema específico que você esteja lidando.

Comment: Carlos, por que essa forma não é recomendada?

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte dá uma olhada aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse